# Bullet fires perfectly in three directions, but not left

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm quite new with actionscript, and have been scrapping together a little test game to sort of get used to the language, get my feet wet. The premise behind the game is pretty average, I have a character that can move in 8 directions, can pick up several keys that are randomly placed, and open a door when he possesses a key.

The problem comes in to play with the bullet shooting. I don't know much about trigonometry, so when a key is pressed, i just use the .rotate property to turn the player. I pass the .rotate integer into my bullet class and use that to tell which direction the bullet should travel. It works perfectly for the up, down, and right movements, but when the character is facing left the bullet is created but has no velocity whatsoever, and for the life of me I cannot figure out where the error in the code is.

If someone could look over my code and help me out, I would be much appreciated. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm just missing. I know it's a bit sloppy, so if there's any other tips you want to pass on to a novice please feel free!!

Thank you so much guys.

Main Class

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.text.TextField;


    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        var player:Player;
        var inventory:Inventory;
        var invArray:Array = new Array();
        var key:_Key;
        var vx:int;
        var maxSpeed:int;
        var key_Up:Boolean;
        var key_Down:Boolean;
        var key_Left:Boolean;
        var key_Right:Boolean;
        var maxKey:int;
        var keyCount:TextField;
        var keysUp:int;
        var door:Door;
        var doorOpen:Boolean;
        var wall1:Wall;
        var wall2:Wall;
        var wallCollide:Boolean;
        var bulletTime:int;
        var bulletLimit:int;
        var bulletShoot:Boolean;
        static var playerRotation:int;


        public function Main()
        {
            init();
        }

        public function init():void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

            initPlayer();
            initVariables();
            initInventory();
            initItems();


        }

        public function gameLoop(e:Event):void
        {
            movePlayer();
            collisionDetection();
            bullet();
        }

        public function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch (e.keyCode)
            {
                case 37 :
                    key_Left = true;
                    break;

                case 38 :
                    key_Up = true;
                    break;

                case 39 :
                    key_Right = true;
                    break;

                case 40 :
                    key_Down = true;
                    break;

                case 32:
                    if(bulletShoot)
                    {
                        bulletShoot = false;
                        var newBullet:Bullet = new Bullet(player.rotation);
                        newBullet.x = player.x;
                        newBullet.y = player.y;
                        addChild(newBullet);

                    }
            }
        }

        public function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch (e.keyCode)
            {
                case 37 :
                    key_Left = false;
                    break;

                case 38 :
                    key_Up = false;
                    break;

                case 39 :
                    key_Right = false;
                    break;

                case 40 :
                    key_Down = false;
                    break;
            }

        }

        public function movePlayer():void
        {
            if (key_Left && !key_Right)
            {
                player.x -=  maxSpeed;
                player.rotation = 270;
            }

            if (key_Right && !key_Left)
            {
                player.x +=  maxSpeed;
                player.rotation = 90;
            }

            if (key_Up && !key_Down)
            {
                player.y -=  maxSpeed;
                player.rotation = 0;
            }

            if (key_Down && !key_Up)
            {
                player.y +=  maxSpeed;
                player.rotation = 180;

            }

            /*if ( key_Left && key_Up && !key_Right && !key_Down )
            {
                player.rotation = 315;
            }
            if ( key_Right && key_Up && !key_Left && !key_Down )
            {
                player.rotation = 45;
            }
            if ( key_Left && key_Down && !key_Right && !key_Up )
            {
                player.rotation = 225;
            }
            if ( key_Right && key_Down && !key_Left && !key_Up )
            {
                player.rotation = 135;
            }*/

        }

        public function initPlayer():void
        {
            player = new Player();
            player.x = stage.stageWidth * .5;
            player.y = stage.stageHeight * .5;
            stage.addChild(player);

        }

        public function initVariables():void
        {
            vx = 0;
            maxSpeed = 4;
            key_Up = false;
            key_Down = false;
            key_Left = false;
            key_Right = false;
            maxKey = 3;
            keysUp = 0;
            doorOpen = false;
            wallCollide = false;
            bulletTime = 0;
            bulletLimit = 12;
            bulletShoot = true ;
        }

        public function collisionDetection():void
        {

            for (var i:int=0; i < invArray.length; i++)
            {
                key = invArray[i];
                if (player.hitTestObject(key))
                {
                    stage.removeChild(key);
                    invArray.splice(i, 1);
                    keysUp++;
                    //trace(keysUp);
                    i--;
                    keyCount.text = String(keysUp);
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (player.hitTestPoint(door.x,door.y + 25,true) && (keysUp > 0) && ! doorOpen)
            {
                door.gotoAndStop(2);
                keysUp--;
                invArray.pop();
                trace(keysUp);
                keyCount.text = String(keysUp);
                doorOpen = true;
            }

            if (player.hitTestObject(door) && (keysUp == 0) && ! doorOpen)
            {
                wallCollide = true;
            }

            if (player.hitTestObject(wall1))
            {

                wallCollide = true;
            }

            if (player.hitTestObject(wall2))
            {
                wallCollide = true;
            }

            if (wallCollide == true)
            {
                player.y +=  4;
                wallCollide = false;
            }


        }

        public function initInventory():void
        {
            inventory = new Inventory();
            inventory.x = stage.stageWidth * .15;
            inventory.y = stage.stageHeight * .90;
            stage.addChild(inventory);

            keyCount = new TextField();
            stage.addChild(keyCount);
            keyCount.x = inventory.x - 8;
            keyCount.y = inventory.y + 3;
            keyCount.text = String(keysUp);
            //keyCount.border = true;
            keyCount.width = 20;
            keyCount.height = 20;

        }

        public function initItems():void
        {

            while (invArray.length < maxKey)
            {
                key = new _Key  ;
                key.x = Math.random() * 550;
                key.y = Math.random() * 300;
                stage.addChild(key);
                invArray.push(key);

            }

            door = new Door();
            door.x = 250;
            door.y = 25;

            wall1 = new Wall();
            stage.addChild(wall1);
            wall1.x = door.x - 175;
            wall1.y = door.y;

            wall2 = new Wall();
            stage.addChild(wall2);
            wall2.x = door.x + 175;
            wall2.y = door.y;

            stage.addChild(door);
        }

        public function bullet():void
        {
            if (bulletTime < bulletLimit)
            {
                bulletTime++;
            } else
            {
                bulletShoot = true;
                bulletTime = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bullet Class

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;


public class Bullet extends MovieClip {

    public var _root:Object;
    public var speed:int = 10;
    public var bulletRotation:int;


    public function Bullet(pRotation:int) {

        addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
        bulletRotation = pRotation;
    }

    private function beginClass(e:Event):void
    {
        _root = MovieClip(root);
    }

    private function eFrame(e:Event):void
    {
        if (bulletRotation == 0)
        {
            this.y -= speed;
        }

        else if (bulletRotation == 90)
        {
            this.x += speed;
        }

        else if(bulletRotation == 270)
        {
            this.x -= speed;
        }

        else if(bulletRotation == 180)
        {
            this.y += speed;
        }

        if(this.y < -1 * this.height)
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
            _root.removeChild(this);
        }

        if(this.x < -1 * this.width)
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
            _root.removeChild(this);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: To resolve similar issues, I highly encourage you put a break point at the line you add bullet to scene and examine the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bullet class, change 270 to -90, at line 38:

```
else if(bulletRotation == -90)
{
     this.x -= speed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I broke down and looked up some trig and solved it that way, but it's great to have that bit of understanding for the future, thank you guys!!